# Print out select options dropdown inside echo

Tags: php

How do I print out select option inside echo ? I have now this:

```
echo '<select name="api_series">
       <?php foreach($series["data"] as $data) { echo <option>$data["id"]</option> } ?>
      </select>';
```

But this doesnt work. How do I make this work I am so confused.

Comment: You already _are_ in a PHP parser block, so using `<?php ... ?>` again inside the string, makes no sense. Just _end_ your echo statement, then do the foreach loop, and then echo the closing select tag after ...

Comment: And if that doesn't help, please expand on "But this doesn't work". What does it do that it should not, or what should it do that it does not? What error messages do you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't open a new PHP code block (with `<?php`) or put a `foreach` loop or an `echo` inside an existing PHP block and echo statement / string. And even if that was possible somehow, it would make no logical sense. You just need to do the loop, concatenate the string as you go along and then echo it. Or you could echo each chunk of content directly as you loop.

For example:

```
$html = '<select name="api_series">';

foreach ($series["data"] as $data) { 
  $html .= '<option>'.$data["id"].'</option>';
} 
$html .= '</select>';

echo $html;
```

Comment: Yea and just add dots ```'<option>'.$data["id"].'</option>';``` it works

Comment: @thisISme good one, I didn't spot that bit. Have updated the answer - thanks